# Allocation Formula

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

I have car repair services shop, there are many services(Diagnosis, Engine Repair. Electrical repairs...) Sequence conservation does not matter

And then I know how much time does one current car needs for single services, for example:

1. Ford - 120 minutes for diagnosis, 360 for engine and 80 for electric repairs
2. BMW - 90 minutes for diagnosis, 480 for engine and 140 for electric repairs
3. Mercedes - 90 minutes for diagnosis, 42 for engine and 160 for electric repairs

Etc. And there is big list of cars.

So is there any good algorithm or mathematical formula which allocates cars optimally into service boxes such don't waste time of boxes and get best result with minimal waiting of cars.

Comment: There are *lots* of algorithms. If you Google for something like "task scheduler algorithm", you'll get lots of hits, most of them relevant (including some to older questions here on SO).

Comment: in your example, you have 3 service boxes(diagnosis, engine and electric)?

Comment: Jerry thank you i ll google it. no Rambo i have 16 and 80 cars

Comment: This is why you buy mercedes <3

Comment: @AK4749 so that you get to go geek mode and help your repair shop reduce their long lines because they're too busy fixing all their high repair rate cars? ;)

Comment: this is an NP-complete problem. the solution takes a heuristic and it depends on the specifics-- fixed (3) #jobs on each vehicle, estimates on the incoming vehicles..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a so-called "Open-Shop" problem. The difference to Job Shop Scheduling is that in the latter the sequence in which jobs are executed on machines is relevant, while this is not the case in your example.

Unfortunately, the problem is NP hard for your case. (For two machines is could be solved in polynomial time.) No need to despair, as there are a number of algorithms that will probably work just fine for your problem size.

Wikipedia has a few good starting points under "Open-Shop Scheduling", with a reference to a classical paper in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called the "Job-Shop Scheduling" problem or sometimes just "Shop-Scheduling." It is widely discussed because it becomes extremely difficult as the number of variables increase (it is what is called an "NP-Hard" problem).

There is no easy answer, but there are several good algorithms to pursue that trade accuracy for calculation time. I suggest the book "[Approximation Algorithms for NP-Hard Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534949681)" edited by Dorit Hochbaum as a resource.